# Jinja2 not getting html template saved in other folder

Tags: python, jinja2

I have two versions of Index.html. One is in the same folder as my main Python File, and the other is in a templates folder.

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
```

WORKS:

```
template = env.get_template('{}'.format(sql_list[7]))
print('{}'.format(sql_list[7]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
  index.html
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
template = env.get_template('../templates/{}'.format(sql_list[7]))
print('../templates/{}'.format(sql_list[7]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
../templates/index.html
```

I don't really understand why it doesn't work since they have the exact same output when printed. But I need to have the file in the Template folder in the end :/. I don't believe it's getting confused with the one in the same folder cause I tried deleting that one and running it again.

Comment: How can `print('../templates/{}'.format(sql_list[7]))` not output at least `../templates/` ?? Are you sure you ran the correct script or something ? I really don't get it, doesn't make sense !

Comment: I had the post formatted incorrectly before. I fixed it now. Not sure why it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.